Use of ものの as a prefix

ハリーはものの見事にロンに負けた。
Harry lost spectacularly to Ron.

Would I be correct in thinking that ものの can be omitted from this sentence?
What is the effect of adding ものの as a prefix? Jisho gives 'only', 'no more than' and 'a matter of' which don't seem to fit in this context. I assume it's acting as some kind of intensifier here.
What words can I add ものの to? I see that ものの見事に is a separate entry in Jisho so I wonder if the use of ものの is limited.


Would I be correct in thinking that ものの can be omitted from this sentence?

Yes, in the sense it doesn't change the fact, but of course as an idiom, it adds more emotional involvement by the speaker. In this case, 見事に would sound more detached, just describing how he is beaten to the ground, while ものの見事に is a nice translation that conveys how the speaker thinks it "spectacular".
I think ものの見事 is one of a kind in the modern language. As for the modifier ものの, it is actually a fairly old phrase meaning "some; a kind of; of that (what you know, what you may call it); quite a", which has left tons of fixed compounds including もののけ and もののあわれ. However, the specific ものの見事 is only found from 1700s.

恋の絆に繋ぎ留め、物の見事に添うてみしよ（近松門左衛門『薩摩歌』（1704））

The only freestanding usage of ものの followed by numerals or quantifiers, which is what you found on Jisho, is even as late as the end of the 19th century. You can translate it with "a matter of" for most times, which emphasizes the smallness of amount, with implication that the action is completed apparently effortlessly or with little resistance.
I guess there was an underlying usage of ものの with a "surprisingly" nuance, then only survived in specialized meanings.

This is interesting. I have always heard もののあわれ (mis?)-translated directly as "the pathos of things" — this etymology would oppose that.

@jogloran もののあわれ is made into a Japanologist term by 本居宣長 and he perhaps read it that way, but when you look at the actual usage of もの in Classical period, it is more like dummy pronoun or placeholder. For example 物に争はず (徒然草) was meant to say "don't be contentious" in English, but as the native vocabulary lacks such a word, he needed to write "fight over sth" where sth is grammatically required but unimportant.

Thanks. I'm intrigued as to what ものの + [numeral]  means.

@user3856370 It's generally as what you found on Jisho, but I'll add it to the answer too.
